# Proof that C is isomorphic to $End_C(V)$ with V the C-vector space C

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I've read that $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(V)$, where $V$ is the $\mathbb C$-vector space $\mathbb C$.
Does somebody know a proof for that?

Greetings,
Peter123.

Comment: What are the $\mathbb{C}$-linear maps $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1):

The isomorphisms $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C)$ and $g:\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C)\rightarrow\mathbb C$ are given explicitly by
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  (f(z))(w)&=&zw\\
  g(\phi)&=&\phi(1)
\end{eqnarray*}$$
To see that $f\circ g$ is the identity, note that
$$
  (f\circ g)(\phi)(z)=f(g(\phi))(z)=f(\phi(1))(z)=\phi(1)z=\phi(z).
$$
It's straightforward but tedious to check all the other properties ($g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb C}$, both are homomorphisms).

Note that this is true if $\mathbb C$ is replaced by any ring with identity (in the non-commutative case some care is needed to say which are left modules and which are right modules).

Comment: Thank you, you helped me very much!

Answer (score 0):

it is well know that if $V$ is a vector $k$-space of dimension $n$
then $End_k(V)$ is isomorphic (not canonical) to the vector
$k$-space of square matrix of seize $n$. so when $V=\Bbb{C}$, the
$End_{\Bbb{C}}(V)$ is isomorphic to $\{(x);x\in \Bbb{C}\}$ and
this last $\Bbb{C}$-space is clearly isomorphic to  $\Bbb{C}$ by
$(x)\rightarrowtail x$.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me very much too!

Comment: thanks, with pleasure